# After multiplication js returns number and NaN

Tags: javascript, android, input, cordova

I'm building an android app using PhoneGap. I'm taking values from number inputs couple times and everything works fine but at one moment it behaves in weird way:

I'm taking values from number inputs and parse it into integers - and everything works fine. But when I multiplicate those values then it gives me in return a value + NaN NaN NaN - it looks like this:

```
var d1;
var d2;
var d3;
d1 = parseInt($('input.inputOne').val());
d2 = parseInt($('input.inputtwo').val());
d3 = ((d1*d2)/10000).toFixed(2);
```

and in console it gives me values:

```
d1
100
d2
200
d3
2.00NaN NaN NaN
```

But if I put d3 into some DOM elements, it simply gives me

```
NaN
```

I've done similiar stuff before in this app and everything was fine - I have no idea why on this particular case it doesn't work - any suggestions?

EDIT:

Funny thing - even if I do e.g.

```
d3 = d2;
```

it gives me

```
d3
200NaN NaN NaN
```

EDIT 2:

More funny stuff - if I don't parse to int values taken from inputs (d1 and d2), after multiplication it gives me:

```
d3
2.00undefined undefined NaN
```

Comment: Please provide actual specifics. `100 * 10` doesn't return anything like `NaN` ever, so you're leaving out some detail(s).

Comment: NaN is usually returned when you try mathematic operations with a member which is null, undefined or Infinity (and Infinity can be returned sometimes with an undefined member).

Comment: You're parseInt should be `parseInt(variable, 10)` where 10 is the base.

Comment: good suggestion @MBillau, but it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what is the issue here. 
You forgot to validate before getting values from input elements. 
I created a demo fiddle for you. You can take a look at it. 
If you changed value in input element to something that is not number(like "abc"); when you will try to parse it to float : its gonna give you error of NaN.. Because it is "Not a Number". I hope this helps. 
http://jsfiddle.net/rahulkhadse/CNB2t/28/

Also to validate input value for numbers only you can refer to following:

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

or you can make use of **"onkeyup"** event and check what type of value user have entered in input box.

P.S: Code on jsFiddle :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    var myVar = $("#validate_info").find('.inputOne').val();
    console.log(myVar);
    var output1 = $('input.inputOne').val();
    console.log(output1);
    var output2 = $('input.inputTwo').val();
    console.log(output2);
    $('#result').html(output1);
    // Starts
    var d1;
    var d2;
    var d3;
    d1 = parseFloat($('input.inputOne').val());
    d2 = parseFloat($('input.inputTwo').val());
    d3 = ((d1 * d2) / 10000).toFixed(2);
    console.log(" With parseFloat d1:" + d1 + ",  d2:" + d2 + ",   d3/result:" + d3);


    d1 = parseInt($('input.inputOne').val());
    d2 = parseInt($('input.inputTwo').val());
    d3 = ((d1 * d2) / 10000).toFixed(2);
    console.log(" With parseInt d1:" + d1 + ",  d2:" + d2 + ",   d3/result:" + d3);

});


    <div id="validate_info">
        <input id="id1" type="text" class="inputOne" value="100" name="abc">
        <input id="id2" type="text" class="inputTwo" value="200" name="abcef">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: thanks - I've tried both solutions which You've provided but still it doesn't work :/ maybe I'll try to emulate this on real android phone instead of emulator and put the result here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it - in the meantime between moment when I've done all the maths and the time when I've put the result into the DOM I was doing empty() on those number inputs - when I stop it then it do maths fine (no multiplication errors etc.) - it is weird I think because I thought that if I do the attribution and after I'll remove the source inputs then it should not affect those variables with input values.